# Как повторить N раз строку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется таблица

```
<table>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

В TR нужно добавить (допустим) 10 раз

```
<td>
    <input ...>
</td>
```

Все вставляемые данные будут идентичны. Можно как то сделать это без цикла? Может есть какая то функция JS, jQuery ?

Как то клонировать это значение и повторить определённое количество раз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вариантов "неважно насколько быстро - главное покороче" есть ещё такой:

```js
var str = "abc";
var count = 10;
var result = new Array(count + 1).join(str);
console.log(result);
```

Работает ли в старых IE - не знаю

Comment: В IE работает =)

Answer (score 3):

Тут поможет функция [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

```js
document.querySelector('tr').innerHTML = `<td>
    <input />
</td>`.repeat(10);
```

```html
<table>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Не работает в IE (

Comment: @Gagablik а чем вам цикл не угодил?

Comment: Цикл беспроигрышный вариант. но думал есть  более правильный способ, так как все значения однотипны